# Cucumber + Capybara file upload not working for me

Tags: ruby, cucumber, sinatra, capybara

I'm trying to test a simple file upload with Capybara. Here is my
Gemfile.lock

```
capybara (1.1.2)
mime-types (>= 1.16)
nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
rack (>= 1.0.0)
rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
selenium-webdriver (~> 2.0)
xpath (~> 0.1.4)
```

and my selenium-webdriver version is 2.18. Here is my web_steps file (it's generated):

```
When /^(?:|I )attach the file "([^\"]*)" to "([^\"]*)"(?: within "([^\"]*)")?$/ do |path, field, selector|
  with_scope(selector) do
    attach_file(field, path)
  end
end
```

This is my feature on the line to upload file:

```
Then I attach the file "features/resources/empty.file" to "file" within "#uploadForm"
```

Actually it ran fine and green on the line, but the input didn't pick up any file so the test failed after that because there was no file selected.

Here is my form:

```
%form#uploadForm{:action => "/upload", :method => "POST", :enctype => "multipart/form-data"}
  %input{:type => "file", :name => "file", :id => "file"}
```

It's pretty basic, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: You're submitting the form you're attaching to, right?

Comment: Yub, sorry I forgot to include the submit button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just wanted to answer my question, the problem is I didn't use the full path. Somehow capybara doesn't recognise relative path.

Answer (score 12):

Toy,
I suggest to:

```
attach_file(field, File.expand_path(path))
```

Instead of using absolute path, especially if you collaborating.

edit: File.expand_path not File.extend_path